# Message would not displayed based on tim

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried to display text on the screen base on the time.

example :

if current time is 12:30 output should be "good after-non Jonh" but in my code something wrong i.e. after 12 pm output default expression . i am not able to find the problem please help me .

```js
let today = new Date();
let hours = today.getHours();
let mins = today.getMinutes();
let seconds = today.getSeconds();
let totalSeconds = hours * 60 * 60 + mins * 60 + seconds;
let msg = "";
let flag;
switch (flag) {
  case totalSeconds >= 0 && totalSeconds <= 43199:
    msg = "Good morning " + value;
    break;
  case totalSeconds >= 43200 && totalSeconds <= 53999:
    msg = "Good Afternon " + value;
    break;
  default:
    msg = "good evening " + value;
    break;
}
return msg;
```

Comment: First figure out what language you want to use.

Comment: `let flag; switch (flag) {` you never assign flag, so you're switching `undefined`. Also, check exactly how a switch statement is to be used. You *can* do what you are trying here, but it's a very bad practice. You most likely want an `if/else` chain.

Answer (score 0):

The `flag` variable is `undefined` and always execute `default` case

You should use `if else` statement instead of `switch`

```
if(totalSeconds >= 0 && totalSeconds <= 43199)
{
    msg = "Good morning " + value;
}
else if(totalSeconds >= 43200 && totalSeconds <= 53999)
{
    msg = "Good Afternon " + value;
}
else {
    msg = "good evening " + value;
}
```